# Найти строку в массиве и взять следующую за ней

Tags: php

```
<?php
$for_edit="подробнее";// искомая строка
$what="кратко\r\n";// на эту меняем

$fopen=@file("21.txt");
foreach($fopen as $key=>$value)
{
  if(substr_count($value,$for_edit))
  {
    // если нашли
    array_splice($fopen, $key, 1, $what); // заменили
  }
  $f=fopen("21.txt", "w"); // переписали файл
  for($i=0;$i<count($fopen);$i++)
  {
    fwrite($f,$fopen[$i]);
  }
  fclose($f);
}
?>
```

Этот скрипт ищет определённую строку и меняет её на нужную, а как сделать, чтобы искалась определённая строка, но менялась следующая, которая идёт после неё?

Comment: Вот как, КАК можно было назвать этот вопрос "запись строки в файл"?

Answer (score 1):

```
array_splice($fopen, $key, 1, $what);
```

Заменить на:

```
    if(isset($fopen[$key+1])){
        array_splice($fopen, $key+1, 1, $what); 
    }
```

P.S. Используйте, в следующий раз, форматирование текста код. А то нереально читать.

Comment: не работает, всё равно заменется та строка которую ищем

Comment: всё работает, проблема в другом была, помощь помогла, спасибо)))